# How to determine if a python package communicates with internet?

Tags: python, network-programming, connectivity

I am doing data science project and I may install some third-party packages to handle my data (notably NLP ones).

As I don't want that my data go on internet, is there any way to analyze if a package communicates with internet ?
More generally, is there any way to shut off network communications for Python (or Spyder) ?

Thanks !

Comment: Which OS are you using (Windows/Linux/Macos) ?

Comment: Currently using windows